# Supervisor terminates after a few seconds

Tags: apache-storm

Supervisor node runs properly for a few seconds, then it terminates..

Can anyone help me to troubleshoot this problem?

This is the errors found in log file associated supervisor

> 2015-10-10 01:11:23 b.s.d.supervisor [ERROR] Error on initialization of server mk-supervisor
>   java.io.IOException: Unable to create directory /home/usr/storm/data/supervisor
>       at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.forceMkdir(FileUtils.java:1488) ~[commons-io-1.4.jar:1.4]
>       at backtype.storm.config$supervisor_local_dir.invoke(config.clj:156) ~[storm-core-0.9.1-incubating.jar:0.9.1-incubating]
>       at backtype.storm.config$supervisor_isupervisor_dir.invoke(config.clj:161) ~[storm-core-0.9.1-incubating.jar:0.9.1-incubating]
>       at backtype.storm.daemon.supervisor$eval5052$exec_fn__1113__auto____5053.invoke(supervisor.clj:362) ~[na:na]
>       at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:167) ~[clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
>       at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:151) ~[clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
>       at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:601) ~[clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
>       at backtype.storm.daemon.supervisor$eval5052$mk_supervisor__5077.doInvoke(supervisor.clj:360) ~[na:na]
>       at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:436) ~[clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
>       at backtype.storm.daemon.supervisor$_launch.invoke(supervisor.clj:514) ~[storm-core-0.9.1-incubating.jar:0.9.1-incubating]
>       at backtype.storm.daemon.supervisor$_main.invoke(supervisor.clj:543) ~[storm-core-0.9.1-incubating.jar:0.9.1-incubating]
>       at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:159) ~[clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
>       at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:151) ~[clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
>       at backtype.storm.daemon.supervisor.main(Unknown Source) ~[storm-core-0.9.1-incubating.jar:0.9.1-incubating]
>   2015-10-10 01:11:23 b.s.util [INFO] Halting process: ("Error on initialization")
>
> 2015-10-10 01:25:16 o.a.z.s.NIOServerCnxn [ERROR] Thread Thread[main,5,main] died
>   org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerException: while scanning a simple key; could not found expected ':';  in 'reader', line 56, column 1:
>       nimbus.thrift.port: 6627
>       ^
>       at org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.stalePossibleSimpleKeys(ScannerImpl.java:460) ~[snakeyaml-1.11.jar:na]
>       at org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.needMoreTokens(ScannerImpl.java:280) ~[snakeyaml-1.11.jar:na]
>       at org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.checkToken(ScannerImpl.java:225) ~[snakeyaml-1.11.jar:na]
>       at org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl$ParseBlockMappingKey.produce(ParserImpl.java:558) ~[snakeyaml-1.11.jar:na]
>       at org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl.peekEvent(ParserImpl.java:158) ~[snakeyaml-1.11.jar:na]
>       at org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl.checkEvent(ParserImpl.java:143) ~[snakeyaml-1.11.jar:na]
>       at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeMappingNode(Composer.java:230) ~[snakeyaml-1.11.jar:na]
>       at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeNode(Composer.java:159) ~[snakeyaml-1.11.jar:na]
>       at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeDocument(Composer.java:122) ~[snakeyaml-1.11.jar:na]
>       at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.getSingleNode(Composer.java:105) ~[snakeyaml-1.11.jar:na]
>       at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.getSingleData(BaseConstructor.java:120) ~[snakeyaml-1.11.jar:na]
>       at org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml.loadFromReader(Yaml.java:481) ~[snakeyaml-1.11.jar:na]
>       at org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml.load(Yaml.java:424) ~[snakeyaml-1.11.jar:na]
>       at backtype.storm.utils.Utils.findAndReadConfigFile(Utils.java:138) ~[storm-core-0.9.1-incubating.jar:0.9.1-incubating]
>       at backtype.storm.utils.Utils.readStormConfig(Utils.java:178) ~[storm-core-0.9.1-incubating.jar:0.9.1-incubating]
>       at backtype.storm.config$read_storm_config.invoke(config.clj:116) ~[storm-core-0.9.1-incubating.jar:0.9.1-incubating]
>       at backtype.storm.daemon.supervisor$_launch.invoke(supervisor.clj:512) ~[storm-core-0.9.1-incubating.jar:0.9.1-incubating]
>       at backtype.storm.daemon.supervisor$_main.invoke(supervisor.clj:543) ~[storm-core-0.9.1-incubating.jar:0.9.1-incubating]
>       at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:159) ~[clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
>       at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:151) ~[clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
>       at backtype.storm.daemon.supervisor.main(Unknown Source) ~[storm-core-0.9.1-incubating.jar:0.9.1-incubating]
>
> 2015-10-10 14:31:09 o.a.z.s.NIOServerCnxn [ERROR] Thread Thread[main,5,main] died
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field storm.zookeeper.servers must be an Iterable of java.lang.String
>       at backtype.storm.ConfigValidation$1.validateField(ConfigValidation.java:63) ~[storm-core-0.9.1-incubating.jar:0.9.1-incubating]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_36]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.6.0_36]
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.6.0_36]
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622) ~[na:1.6.0_36]
>       at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeMatchingMethod(Reflector.java:93) ~[clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
>       at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeInstanceMethod(Reflector.java:28) ~[clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
>       at backtype.storm.config$validate_configs_with_schemas.invoke(config.clj:112) ~[storm-core-0.9.1-incubating.jar:0.9.1-incubating]
>       at backtype.storm.config$read_storm_config.invoke(config.clj:117) ~[storm-core-0.9.1-incubating.jar:0.9.1-incubating]
>       at backtype.storm.daemon.supervisor$_launch.invoke(supervisor.clj:512) ~[storm-core-0.9.1-incubating.jar:0.9.1-incubating]
>       at backtype.storm.daemon.supervisor$_main.invoke(supervisor.clj:543) ~[storm-core-0.9.1-incubating.jar:0.9.1-incubating]
>       at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:159) ~[clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
>       at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:151) ~[clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
>       at backtype.storm.daemon.supervisor.main(Unknown Source) ~[storm-core-0.9.1-incubating.jar:0.9.1-incubating]
>
> 2015-11-24 22:07:28 c.n.c.ConnectionState [ERROR] Connection timed out
>   org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss
>       at com.netflix.curator.ConnectionState.getZooKeeper(ConnectionState.java:72) ~[curator-client-1.0.1.jar:na]
>       at com.netflix.curator.CuratorZookeeperClient.getZooKeeper(CuratorZookeeperClient.java:74) ~[curator-client-1.0.1.jar:na]
>       at com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.getZooKeeper(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:353) ~[curator-framework-1.0.1.jar:na]
>       at com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.BackgroundSyncImpl.performBackgroundOperation(BackgroundSyncImpl.java:39) ~[curator-framework-1.0.1.jar:na]
>       at com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.OperationAndData.callPerformBackgroundOperation(OperationAndData.java:40) ~[curator-framework-1.0.1.jar:na]
>       at com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.backgroundOperationsLoop(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:547) ~[curator-framework-1.0.1.jar:na]
>       at com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.access$200(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:50) ~[curator-framework-1.0.1.jar:na]
>       at com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl$2.call(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:177) ~[curator-framework-1.0.1.jar:na]
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334) ~[na:1.6.0_36]
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166) ~[na:1.6.0_36]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146) ~[na:1.6.0_36]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) ~[na:1.6.0_36]
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701) ~[na:1.6.0_36]
>   2015-11-24 22:07:30 c.n.c.ConnectionState [ERROR] Connection timed out
>   org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss
>       at com.netflix.curator.ConnectionState.getZooKeeper(ConnectionState.java:72) ~[curator-client-1.0.1.jar:na]
>       at com.netflix.curator.CuratorZookeeperClient.getZooKeeper(CuratorZookeeperClient.java:74) ~[curator-client-1.0.1.jar:na]
>       at com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.getZooKeeper(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:353) ~[curator-framework-1.0.1.jar:na]
>       at com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.SetDataBuilderImpl$2.call(SetDataBuilderImpl.java:139) ~[curator-framework-1.0.1.jar:na]
>       at com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.SetDataBuilderImpl$2.call(SetDataBuilderImpl.java:135) ~[curator-framework-1.0.1.jar:na]
>       at com.netflix.curator.RetryLoop.callWithRetry(RetryLoop.java:85) ~[curator-client-1.0.1.jar:na]
>       at com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.SetDataBuilderImpl.pathInForeground(SetDataBuilderImpl.java:131) ~[curator-framework-1.0.1.jar:na]
>       at com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.SetDataBuilderImpl.forPath(SetDataBuilderImpl.java:123) ~[curator-framework-1.0.1.jar:na]
>       at com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.SetDataBuilderImpl.forPath(SetDataBuilderImpl.java:33) ~[curator-framework-1.0.1.jar:na]
>       at backtype.storm.zookeeper$set_data.invoke(zookeeper.clj:137) ~[storm-core-0.9.1-incubating.jar:0.9.1-incubating]
>       at backtype.storm.cluster$mk_distributed_cluster_state$reify__2057.set_ephemeral_node(cluster.clj:72) ~[na:na]
>       at backtype.storm.cluster$mk_storm_cluster_state$reify__2486.supervisor_heartbeat_BANG_(cluster.clj:315) ~[na:na]
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor11.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.6.0_36]
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622) ~[na:1.6.0_36]
>       at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeMatchingMethod(Reflector.java:93) ~[clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
>       at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeInstanceMethod(Reflector.java:28) ~[clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
>       at backtype.storm.daemon.supervisor$eval5052$exec_fn__1113__auto____5053$heartbeat_fn__5055.invoke(supervisor.clj:378) ~[na:na]
>       at backtype.storm.timer$schedule_recurring$this__1813.invoke(timer.clj:92) ~[na:na]
>       at backtype.storm.timer$mk_timer$fn__1796$fn__1797.invoke(timer.clj:48) ~[na:na]
>       at backtype.storm.timer$mk_timer$fn__1796.invoke(timer.clj:41) ~[na:na]
>       at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24) ~[clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701) ~[na:1.6.0_36]
>   2015-11-24 22:07:31 c.n.c.ConnectionState [ERROR] Connection timed out
>   org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss
>       at com.netflix.curator.ConnectionState.getZooKeeper(ConnectionState.java:72) ~[curator-client-1.0.1.jar:na]
>       at com.netflix.curator.CuratorZookeeperClient.getZooKeeper(CuratorZookeeperClient.java:74) ~[curator-client-1.0.1.jar:na]
>       at com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.getZooKeeper(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:353) ~[curator-framework-1.0.1.jar:na]
>       at com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.BackgroundSyncImpl.performBackgroundOperation(BackgroundSyncImpl.java:39) ~[curator-framework-1.0.1.jar:na]
>       at com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.OperationAndData.callPerformBackgroundOperation(OperationAndData.java:40) ~[curator-framework-1.0.1.jar:na]
>       at com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.backgroundOperationsLoop(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:547) ~[curator-framework-1.0.1.jar:na]
>       at com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.access$200(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:50) ~[curator-framework-1.0.1.jar:na]
>       at com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl$2.call(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:177) ~[curator-framework-1.0.1.jar:na]
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334) ~[na:1.6.0_36]
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166) ~[na:1.6.0_36]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146) ~[na:1.6.0_36]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) ~[na:1.6.0_36]
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701) ~[na:1.6.0_36]
>   2015-11-24 22:07:32 c.n.c.ConnectionState [ERROR] Connection timed out
>   org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss
>       at com.netflix.curator.ConnectionState.getZooKeeper(ConnectionState.java:72) ~[curator-client-1.0.1.jar:na]
>       at com.netflix.curator.CuratorZookeeperClient.getZooKeeper(CuratorZookeeperClient.java:74) ~[curator-client-1.0.1.jar:na]
>       at com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.getZooKeeper(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:353) ~[curator-framework-1.0.1.jar:na]
>       at com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.BackgroundSyncImpl.performBackgroundOperation(BackgroundSyncImpl.java:39) ~[curator-framework-1.0.1.jar:na]
>       at com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.OperationAndData.callPerformBackgroundOperation(OperationAndData.java:40) ~[curator-framework-1.0.1.jar:na]
>       at com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.backgroundOperationsLoop(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:547) ~[curator-framework-1.0.1.jar:na]
>       at com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.access$200(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:50) ~[curator-framework-1.0.1.jar:na]
>       at com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl$2.call(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:177) ~[curator-framework-1.0.1.jar:na]
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334) ~[na:1.6.0_36]
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166) ~[na:1.6.0_36]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146) ~[na:1.6.0_36]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) ~[na:1.6.0_36]
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701) ~[na:1.6.0_36]
>   2015-11-24 22:07:37 c.n.c.ConnectionState [ERROR] Connection timed out
>   org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss
>       at com.netflix.curator.ConnectionState.getZooKeeper(ConnectionState.java:72) ~[curator-client-1.0.1.jar:na]
>       at com.netflix.curator.CuratorZookeeperClient.getZooKeeper(CuratorZookeeperClient.java:74) ~[curator-client-1.0.1.jar:na]
>       at com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.getZooKeeper(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:353) ~[curator-framework-1.0.1.jar:na]
>       at com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.BackgroundSyncImpl.performBackgroundOperation(BackgroundSyncImpl.java:39) ~[curator-framework-1.0.1.jar:na]
>       at com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.OperationAndData.callPerformBackgroundOperation(OperationAndData.java:40) ~[curator-framework-1.0.1.jar:na]
>       at com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.backgroundOperationsLoop(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:547) ~[curator-framework-1.0.1.jar:na]
>       at com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.access$200(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:50) ~[curator-framework-1.0.1.jar:na]
>       at com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl$2.call(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:177) ~[curator-framework-1.0.1.jar:na]
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334) ~[na:1.6.0_36]
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166) ~[na:1.6.0_36]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146) ~[na:1.6.0_36]
>          at   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:61   5) ~[na:1.6.0_36]
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701) ~[na:1.6.0_36]

Comment: did you try to search for additional flags to put at start that would give you some logs to display? I'm afraid it's gonna be hard to help you much without any error to start with...

Comment: There's an option that you can specify declaring your topology in your Java class. `topology.debug`, set that to true to see debug info.

Comment: You can enable debug mode in `storm.yaml` file. Please post the logs the supervisor generates at startup. You can find them in the `logs` directory.